# How to use PFTron WebViewer on my Electron app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, pdftron

I want to use PDFTron webviewer on my app. How I do it? "NOTE: I installed @pdftron node module"

[image]

Comment: did you find an answer to your question? Did the answer below work? If so, please mark it as the answer. If not, then please update the question. Others might want to know the answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely is possible to use WebViewer in an Electron app. I would recommend checking out the Electron set up guide and verify that you are set up properly. You can find the details as well as a sample here: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/get-started/electron/.

Areas to take note of is the WebViewer **lib** folder under the **public** folder and **App.js** where WebViewer is initialized.

Let me know if this helps!